# Analyzing diseased-based data "backwards"?

Tags: modeling, multivariate-analysis, disease

In my line of work, we have clinical samples from various stages of a pathology. We might measure levels of proteins, RNAs, etc.--we'll call them all "markers". Invariably, the presumption is that I would analyze the data thus:

$$\text{marker} \sim \text{Diagnosis } (\times \text{ covariates})$$

And present the results. Essentially, the model states that the marker is an outcome of the disease state, then we write the papers to try to demonstrate that the disease state is influenced by the marker level (the reverse of the model structure).

Conceptually, is there anything wrong with the following:

$$\text{Diagnosis } \sim \text{marker}_1 + \text{marker}_2 + \text{marker}_n\  (\times \text{ covariates})$$

as a binomial or multinomial model for "Diagnosis" and presenting the effects of markers in concert on the outcome of disease state? In other words, explicitly model what the paper is trying to claim. It also allows me to model several markers as a multiple regression (glm).

Or is this just not biologically valid?

Comment: If you are trying to predict the diagnosis based on the markers then your second model makes statistical sense.

Comment: The medical hypothesis is that changes in the markers lead to the diagnosis, so yes. That is what we are trying to predict. I wonder why I have to explain this to senior faculty when I present data in this fashion.

Comment: You might need to explain better what markers are and what diagnosis is and how they arise (what theoretical model/relationship) and how they get measured.

Comment: Marker: brain protein levels such as APP, MME, REST, etc.
Diagnosis: AD vs non-cognitively impaired.
Theoretical relationship: Marker levels influence risk of developing AD.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert on causal modelling, but it may be worth investigating what sort of DAG each model implies.  Then, you can compare this against the expert knowledge in your field to decide which model to pursue.

The first model you have written implies a causal model shown below.  Here, the biomarker is the outcome, and the covairates are a common cause of both the diagnosis and the biomarker.  Were we to condition on covariates and modulate the diagnosis, this would neccesarily change the biomarker.

[image]

Now, doesn't that seem a bit strange?  I'll repeat what I said: *"A change in the diagnosis would cause a change in the biomarker"*.  If that is the case, your colleagues would have to present the mechanism by which the biomarker can somehow listen to our diagnosis.  I'm being a bit fast and loose here.  I haven't defined what I mean by diagnosis, and this model may be entirely plausible if perhaps the biomarker is indeed caused by some different disease state (e.g. perhaps the disease is effecting a different part of the body than the one the disease is primarily associated with).

Compare this to the alternative model you've presented.  Here the diagnosis is the outcome, and the causal phrase "modulating the bio marker causes a change in the diagnosis" doesn't seem as strange.

[image]

This post is not so much an answer of the kind you expect.  I don't think providing your colleagues with references will do you much good (for they could and likely will present papers to you which do it their way.  My experience with clinical work is that people want to do what other people are doing).  The solution will come from thinking about what sort of implications your model is making.  To that end, I think its important you provide us more details about the diagnosis, the study, the biomarkers etc so that we can reason through the model implications together.

Comment: You've gotten to the heart of the matter (+1). The word "biomarker" is used in several different contexts, making it critical to think through the logic of the specific situation for each application. As the OP asks for a reference in support, I'd suggest the Hernán and Robins [Causal Inference book](https://www.hsph.harvard.edu/miguel-hernan/causal-inference-book/) as a recent, accessible, and freely-available source.

Comment: Diagnosis: Alzheimer's disease vs not cognitively impaired. Biomarkers: Levels of the proteins REST, MME, APP in the brain. The THEORY is that levels of REST, MME, and APP (among others) influence the risk of getting AD. The practice in the literature is to test the hypothesis that AD alters the levels of these proteins in the brain (that is, APP, MME, REST, et al are treated like response variables while AD diagnosis is treated like the predictor--100% exactly the OPPOSITE of the paradigm of the field).

Comment: I was hoping to get a strong theoretical paper that justified the use of a logistic model that explicitly tested marker -> diagnosis instead of creating models that all test diagnosis -> marker and then claiming any significant result supported the hypothesis marker -> diagnosis.

Comment: @Bryan A paper which tested marker -> diagnosis isn't really a statistical question, and one for someone more familiar with the Alzheimer's literature.  If the theory, as you've said, is that the markers modulate the risk, then the risk of Alzheimer's should be the dependent variable in the model.

Comment: @Bryan In my estimation, your approach is the correct one and were I a reviewer I would likely comment on the exposure of interest being treated as the outcome.  I think I've said all I can at this point.  If you need a paper, I think you're going to have to search for it.  All I can provide is more arguments, but it doesn't sound like that would help.